# Debugging linker error with Xcode - sdl static library

Tags: xcode, sdl

I am trying to follow this guide here for building SDL2 for iOS:

http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/52_hello_mobile/ios_mac/index.php

I am able to build the libSDL2.a static library, however I am getting a linker error when I attempt to build his example hello world application which uses it.

```
Ld /Users/testuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/___PROJECTNAME___-egvszvnfjpicgqdtaazpczjuebut/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/___PROJECTNAME___.app/___PROJECTNAME___ normal x86_64
    cd "/Users/testuser/Documents/iosBuild/SDL iOS Application"
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.0.sdk -L/Users/testuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/___PROJECTNAME___-egvszvnfjpicgqdtaazpczjuebut/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/testuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/___PROJECTNAME___-egvszvnfjpicgqdtaazpczjuebut/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/testuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/___PROJECTNAME___-egvszvnfjpicgqdtaazpczjuebut/Build/Intermediates/___PROJECTNAME___.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/___PROJECTNAME___.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/___PROJECTNAME___.LinkFileList -mios-simulator-version-min=10.0 -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/testuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/___PROJECTNAME___-egvszvnfjpicgqdtaazpczjuebut/Build/Intermediates/___PROJECTNAME___.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/___PROJECTNAME___.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/___PROJECTNAME____lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -lSDL2 -framework GameController -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreAudio -framework AudioToolbox -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreMotion -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/testuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/___PROJECTNAME___-egvszvnfjpicgqdtaazpczjuebut/Build/Intermediates/___PROJECTNAME___.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/___PROJECTNAME___.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/___PROJECTNAME____dependency_info.dat -o /Users/testuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/___PROJECTNAME___-egvszvnfjpicgqdtaazpczjuebut/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/___PROJECTNAME___.app/___PROJECTNAME___

ld: library not found for -lSDL2
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Per his instructions, I copied the project template and added the libSDL2.a lib that I built under the Build Phases -> link binary with libraries menu:

[image]

Any suggestions for how I can debug this problem?

Edit: My build target configuration in the project which uses the library:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the architecture is correct? If you build it separately for the device, you won't be able to use it in the simulator... First check that...

Comment: I believe I built it for the correct target, but therein lies my question, I'm not sure how to be certain. When I run this the lipo tool this is my output against the library I built to run in the iphone 5 simulator: lipo -info libSDL2.a input file libSDL2.a is not a fat file Non-fat file: libSDL2.a is architecture: i386

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to build your library with this script. the final product will be placed in your home ~/SDL directory.

```
#!/bin/sh

PREFIX=$HOME/SDL
SYMROOT="SYMROOT=$PREFIX/release"

SDK_DEVICE="-sdk iphoneos"
SDK_SIMULATOR="-sdk iphonesimulator"
CONF_DEBUG="-configuration Debug"
CONF_RELEASE="-configuration Release"

mkdir -p $PREFIX
cd $PREFIX

wget https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL2-2.0.4.zip
unzip SDL2-2.0.4.zip
rm -f SDL2-2.0.4.zip

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
# SDL
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
cd $PREFIX/SDL2-2.0.4/Xcode-iOS/SDL
SCHEME="libSDL"
PROJ="-project SDL.xcodeproj"

#xcodebuild OTHER_CFLAGS="-fembed-bitcode" OTHER_LDFLAGS="-lobjc"   ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -arch i386 -arch x86_64 $PROJ $SDK_SIMULATOR      $CONF_DEBUG   -scheme='$SCHEME' build      $SYMROOT
xcodebuild OTHER_CFLAGS="-fembed-bitcode"  ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -arch i386 -arch x86_64 $PROJ $SDK_SIMULATOR  $CONF_RELEASE -scheme='$SCHEME' build      $SYMROOT
#xcodebuild OTHER_CFLAGS="-fembed-bitcode" OTHER_LDFLAGS="-lobjc" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -arch arm64 -arch armv7 $PROJ $SDK_DEVICE      $CONF_DEBUG   -scheme='$SCHEME' build      $SYMROOT
xcodebuild OTHER_CFLAGS="-fembed-bitcode"  ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -arch arm64 -arch armv7 $PROJ $SDK_DEVICE     $CONF_RELEASE -scheme='$SCHEME' build      $SYMROOT

lipo $PREFIX/release/Release-iphonesimulator/libSDL2.a $PREFIX/release/Release-iphoneos/libSDL2.a -create -output $PREFIX/libSDL2.a
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't realize this cli existed for xcode. I was able to use your script to build the library, I then modified it to build the project which uses the library. This will be a great way to streamline my iOS target build process, really appreciate the tip

Comment: glad i could help. the solution is even more powerfull when building all the sdl libs - sdl2_ttf, sdl2_image, sdl2_mixer and sdl2_net. it can really save some time.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely that the static library you built does not contain the architecture for which you're building your application. You'll need to build a static library that contains the architectures for the platform you want to build.

Also, keep in mind that it's not actually supported to put architectures for different platforms (such as iOS and tvOS, or even iOS and iOS Simulator—the simulators are separate platforms) in a single binary. You'll need a separate library or framework for each platform you're targeting, though each one can of course contain slices for all of that platform's supported architectures.

Comment: As far as I can tell, I built it for the correct target, but therein lies my question, I'm not sure how to be certain. When I run this the lipo tool this is my output against the library I built to run in the iphone 5 simulator: lipo -info libSDL2.a 
input file libSDL2.a is not a fat file
Non-fat file: libSDL2.a is architecture: i386

Comment: In your command above, you have "...clang -arch x86_64" so you're trying to link a i386 static archive to an x86_64 binary.

Comment: How could I change it? I've added a screenshot of the build configuration for this project, I see 2 fields: architectures and valid architectures, but neither list x86_64